# replication listener in publish aem

Tags: aem

I am trying to write a listener which listens to page activation but in Publish Environment. The code which I have written works in author environment but doesn't in publish, i.e. it doesn't listen to  Replication even in pub environment. I have attached the underlying code. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
package com.whirlpool.portal.services.listeners;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
import org.osgi.service.event.Event;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventConstants;
import org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.day.cq.replication.ReplicationAction;
import com.day.cq.workflow.event.WorkflowEvent;
//Sling Imports


/**
 * Just a simple DS Component
 */
@Component
@Service
@Properties({
    @Property(
            label = "Event Topics",
            value = { ReplicationAction.EVENT_TOPIC },
            description = "[Required] Event Topics this event handler will to respond to.",
            name = EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC,
            propertyPrivate = true
    ),
    @Property(
            label = "Event Filters",
            value = "(" + ReplicationAction.PROPERTY_TYPE + "=ACTIVATE)",
            name = EventConstants.EVENT_FILTER,
            propertyPrivate = true
    )
})
public class SimpleDSComponent implements Runnable, EventHandler {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());



    private BundleContext bundleContext;


    public void handleEvent(Event event) {

        String n[] = event.getPropertyNames();

        log.info("");

        log.info("Event occurred: {}", event.getProperty(WorkflowEvent.EVENT_TYPE));

        log.info("Event properties: ");

        for(String s : n) {

            log.info(s + " = " + event.getProperty(s));

        }



        ReplicationAction action = ReplicationAction.fromEvent(event);

        if(action != null) {

            log.info("Replication action {} occured on {} ", action.getType().getName(), action.getPath());
            log.info("Tushar Replication");

        }

        log.info("");

    }


    public void run() {
        log.info("Running...");
    }

    protected void activate(ComponentContext ctx) {
        this.bundleContext = ctx.getBundleContext();
    }

    protected void deactivate(ComponentContext ctx) {
        this.bundleContext = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you have admin/replication access on publish env, can you try activating the page on publish. I suspect the replication event "Activate" is triggered on author, as  "Activate" happens on author.

Comment: Though manual activation on publish is not valid use case. There is OnRecieve configuration in Replication Agent which is used on relaying activation from publish to other publish servers.

Comment: I think you would have a "create" and "modify" listener on nodes on the publish environment as the activation does nothing more than a POST to the publisher. As Sandeep mentioned the activate event is only triggered on the author.

Answer (score 5):

Please see http://www.javaarticles.com/aem/how-to-create-replication-event-listeners-in-author-publisher.

The key difference is that for author instance event topic is  com/day/cq/replication and for publisher event topic is com/adobe/granite/replication (ReplicationEvent.EVENT_TOPIC vs. ReplicationAction.EVENT_TOPIC).